# Google Form + Apps Script onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

So, I have a Google Form that outputs the data to a Spreadsheet. I have written some code for the onEdit function of the Spreadsheet to strip out all non-numeric characters for phone numbers. This works just fine if I edit the spreadsheet directly, but when data is entered via the form it doesn't look like the onEdit event is firing off. Is there something I need to do with the form to get it to fire off the onEdit on the Spreadhseet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special trigger for form submission called [on Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR#ActionTriggers) that you should install from the ressource menu in the script editor.

Depending on your actual code you might need to change a few things in your script but it might also be possible to use the very same function you use with onEdit.

Please consider showing your code if you want a more accurate answer.