# Form submission Delete row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, triggers

I have been using the following code to move and delete row upon completion of line item,

I have now moved from manual entries to line entries via google form and have not been able to achieve the same results.

Any Ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

I assume that the form submissions are behaving differently and I just have not found the right commands to make it work correctly

```
function onEdit(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Open Tickets" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed Tickets");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Closed Tickets" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Open Tickets");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context and a more exact description of your workflow before and after the change you mentioned. A properly reproducible example might help.

Comment: onEdit() triggers only occur on user actions.

Comment: Using this as a generic ticketing system, Form will now be submitted for ticket, Once task is completed it is marked completed in col P and is moved to a closed ticket tab. with using the form submit the data does not move from form submission page. I guess another option is to leave the Form Responses 1 tab and copy new entries to the open tickets tab and use the current script as is but I am also having issues appending data from the form response 1 tab to the open tickets tab

Comment: function copyData(e) {
       var sheetName = e.namedValues['Open Tickets'][0];
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      if (!sheet) {
        sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
        var formSheet = e.range.getSheet();
        var headers = formSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, formSheet.getLastColumn());
        headers.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 1));
      }
      sheet.appendRow(e.values);
    }

Answer (score 1):

As you moved from manual entry to the use of a Google Form you can't use anymore an "on edit" trigger but you could use an form submit installable trigger.

Related

- [Google Form + Apps Script onEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19057300/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers